# Meteor display array inside a collection

Tags: javascript, model, meteor

I want create a posts model, with tags, and be able to display all tags for each post. You know a best way to do it ??

I tried this

```
<template name='postsLists'>
  {{#each post}}
    {{> postDetails }}
  {{/each}}
</template>


<template name='postDetails'>
  title: {{title}}
  {{#each tag}}
    {{tag}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use `this` keyword to get value from an array:

```
<template name='postDetails'>
  title: {{title}}
  {{#each tag}}
    {{this}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

This code won't work:

```
{{#each tag}}
  {{tag}}
{{/each}}
```

because "tag" here refers to both the list and an element in that list. Try:

```
{{#each tags}}
  {{tag}}
{{/each}}
```