# How to search in meteor, inside of an array in a collection?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-easy-search

I have the following two schemas,

```
Schema.extraOptions = new SimpleSchema({

name: {
    type: String
},
content: {
    type: String
},
note: {
    type: String
}

});



var wordFields = {
_id: {
    type: String,
    optional: true,
    autoform: {
        omit: true
    }
},
name: {
    type: String,
    label: 'Name'
}
'extraOptions.$': {
    type: Schema.extraOptions,
    optional: true
}
};
```

How can I search in wordFields for name, extraOptions.name and extraOptions.content?

I tried using `easySearch` but it is not working as expected.

```
WordsIndex = new EasySearch.Index({
collection: Words,
fields: ['name', '_id', 'extraOptions' ],
selectorPerField: function (field, searchString) {
    console.log("searchString " + searchString);
    console.log("field " + field);
    if ('extraOptions' === field) {
        // return this selector if the email field is being searched
        console.log("searchString " + searchString);
        console.log("field " + field);
        return {
            extraOptions: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    name: { '$regex' : '.*' + searchString + '.*', '$options' : 'i' },
                    content: { '$regex' : '.*' + searchString + '.*', '$options' : 'i' }
                }
            }
        };
    }
    return this.defaultConfiguration().selectorPerField(field, searchString);
},

engine: new EasySearch.Minimongo()
});
```

Which way would be the best to search values in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219222/meteor-display-array-inside-a-collection?rq=1). Here says that you should access the variables with the keyword `this`