# Meteor : display array inside a collection

Tags: arrays, templates, meteor, collections, meteor-blaze

I checked this question [Meteor display array inside a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219222/meteor-display-array-inside-a-collection) but the solution it doesn't work for me. I have the following templates:

```
<template name="remesasList"> 
    <table class="table table-sm" id="remesasList">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Dia emitido</th>
                <th>Nombre deudor</th>
                <th>Nombre de Factura</th>
                <th>Importe</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {{#each remesas}}
                {{> remesa}}
            {{/each}}  
        </tbody>
    </table>   
</template>
```

I obtain the collection remesas from remesasList.js:

```
Template.remesasList.onCreated(function remesasListOnCreated() {

 var self = this;
 self.autorun(function(){
  remesasHandle = self.subscribe('remesas', {
    onError: function (error) { console.log("onError", error.reason); }
  });
  self.state = new ReactiveDict();
  self.state.set("currentdate", new Date().getTime());
});
});

Template.remesasList.helpers({
  remesas() {
    if( remesasHandle && remesasHandle.ready() ) {
    const instance = Template.instance();
      var currentdate = new Date(instance.state.get("currentdate"));
      var firstDay = new Date(currentdate.getFullYear(), currentdate.getMonth(), 1);
      var lastDay = new Date(currentdate.getFullYear(), currentdate.getMonth() + 1, 0);
      console.log(firstDay);
      moment.locale('es');
      return Remesas.find({dia_emitido: {$gte: firstDay, $lte: lastDay}});
    } else {
      console.log("No hay remesas");
    }
  },
```

I iterate over that collection for each remesa:

```
<template name="remesa">

  <tr id={{_id}} class="js-row-info">
      <td>{{fecha_default dia_emitido}}</td>
      <td>{{nombre_deudor}}</td>
      <td>{{nombre_factura}}</td>
      <td>{{importe_total}}</td>
      <td>{{boolean_a_si_no pagado}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
    <div>
        {{#each item in items}}
            {{item.tipo}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
  </td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

I have the following object remesa that I would like to display all the "tipo" fields:

```
{
 "_id" : "qHDQypADCGodRDFt7",
 "dia_emitido" : ISODate("2017-03-24T23:00:00Z"),
 "nombre_deudor" : "asdsad", 
 "nombre_factura" : "asdsa", 
 "items" : [ 
    { "numeroItem" : 1, "tipo" : "Alquiler", "concepto" : ISODate("2017-02-28T23:00:00Z"), "importe" : 1111 }, 
    { "numeroItem" : 2, "tipo" : "Alquiler", "concepto" : ISODate("2017-02-28T23:00:00Z"), "importe" : 2222 }, 
    { "numeroItem" : 3, "tipo" : "Alquiler", "concepto" : ISODate("2017-09-30T22:00:00Z"), "importe" : 789 }, 
    { "nombre" : "Item 4", "tipo" : "Otro", "concepto" : "un concepto", "importe" : 124578 } 
    ], 
 "numero_de_items" : 4, 
 "importe_total" : 128700 
}
```

When I run this code I had the following error:

```
Exception from Tracker recompute function:
meteor.js?hash=27829e9…:930 Error: {{#each}} currently only accepts arrays, cursors or falsey values.
    at badSequenceError (observe-sequence.js?hash=14ae414…:174)
    at observe-sequence.js?hash=14ae414…:139
    at Object.Tracker.nonreactive (tracker.js?hash=9f8a0ce…:631)
    at observe-sequence.js?hash=14ae414…:116
    at Tracker.Computation._compute (tracker.js?hash=9f8a0ce…:339)
    at new Tracker.Computation (tracker.js?hash=9f8a0ce…:229)
    at Object.Tracker.autorun (tracker.js?hash=9f8a0ce…:604)
    at Object.observe (observe-sequence.js?hash=14ae414…:113)
    at Blaze.View.<anonymous> (blaze.js?hash=813922c…:2819)
    at fireCallbacks (blaze.js?hash=813922c…:2013)
```

Any suggestions why the each section fails? I thought that items is an array...

Comment: What is `remesas` in your first template (e.g. `{{#each remesas}}`).  Is it a template helper or data in the template context (e.g. `this.remesas`)?.  Can you update your question and explain how that var is set?

Comment: Please post the js for the remesa template: in particular, we need to see the code where you get "items".

Comment: @dnszero I don't extract the "items" in remesa.js. Items is an array inside the collection.  I recover the collection remesas in remesasList.js. I have added the code to the question.

Comment: Everything looks fine as far as I can tell. Time for boring troubleshooting... 

Here's how I'd do it: (1) Remove the #each block in question and run the code. (2) Does everything else look ok? (3) If not, check #each remesa block and make sure that query is returning good results. (4) If so, investigate items: console.log() it out and make sure it is what you think it is.

Sorry I can't help more, but I don't see any obvious problems otherwise.

Comment: Thanks @dnszero, I know the right remesa is returned because I can see the other fields displayed correctly when I delete the {{each }}block. Also if I print the {{items}} what I can see is [Object object] [Object object] [Object object]. For some unknown reason I can't iterate through these objects...